# how to access the yml file from application.js in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, yaml

I have a yml file and i need the keys to be used in the application.js file in the scripts. I cannot able to access it from the script. Please help me. I have the following lines in the initializer

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/filename.yml")[Rails.env]
```

and i have the following keys in my yml file

```
development:
  key1: 782364764527225794828437
  key2: sdjfbjs7e834284383984729
  key3: 73465365egfrf36462874727
```

and i access the keys in application.js file as

```
APP_CONFIG['key1']
```

but it seems to take nothing. But when i print the same thing in the view body as

```
<%= APP_CONFIG['key1'] %>
```

then it returns the value of the key1.

What should i do to access the value in application.js file. It also not works in the script body in the view itself.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot execute ruby command in a Javascript file

You need to figure out some other way to load the values in  application.js

Like initialize them in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as a global variable

```
<script>
  var key = '<%= APP_CONFIG['key1'] %>';
</script>
```

and use it in any Javscript file

```
 window.onload=function(){ alert(key);};
```

Comment: but i do not want my keys to be exposed when i view the page source. How can i prevent this from being displayed?

Comment: Javascript is executed in client side. If you want to prevent then you need to perform those operations in rails and just give the result

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly access your yml file content from JS file. What you can do is
on your view page assign these keys to a js variable then it will be available to you for JS work

```
<script>
  var appConfigKeys = “<%= j APP_CONFIG.to_json.html_safe %>”;
  console.log(appConfigKeys);
</script>
```

If you want it to be available in other JS file as then you need to take help of global varibales.

```
<script>
  appConfigKeys = “<%= j APP_CONFIG.to_json.html_safe %>”;
  console.log(appConfigKeys);
</script>
```

Above solution will give you all the keys as a javascript hash
If you need only first key, you can assign single key to a JS variable.

```
<script>
  appConfigKey = “<%= APP_CONFIG['key1'] %>”;
  console.log(appConfigKey);
</script>
```

Comment: but i do not want my keys to be exposed when i view the page source.  How can i prevent this from being displayed?

Comment: If you use global variable, it will be exposed. What you can do is use local variable.

<script>
  var appConfigKey = “<%= APP_CONFIG['key1'] %>”;
  // this appConfigKey will be available in this scope of code and   will not be exposed to end user. 
</script>

You can cross check variable value using alert or console.log

Comment: Variable scope has nothing to do with this, whatever JS code you write it will be exposed and executed in browser

Comment: Yes, JS code always executes in browser. But those variable values are known to browser not to end user. Global variable's value can be accessed in browser console by end the user.

Comment: he says "i do not want my keys to be exposed when i view the page source"

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question since I needed access to my Rails locale YAML from JS, more specifically the months array stored in there. My solution has been to create some HTML with the values I need with ERB and set `display: none` on the parent div (done here using bootstrap's `d-none` class).

In the locale YAML:

```
en:
  date:
    month_names: [~, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
```

In the view:

```
<ul class="d-none" id="months">
  <%= I18n.t('date.month_names').each do |month_name| %>
    <% if month_name.present? %>
      <li><%= month_name %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

In the JS file:

```
const months = document.getElementById('months');
```